# Remove items in array if they are next to each other and get duplicate count

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a console like the one in browsers, but got stuck on displaying duplicate messages I.E if you type `[...Array(10)].map(x => console.log("hello"))` in the console It will print `(10) hello`

So let's say I got this array:

```
const array = [
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
    {
        output: "hello",
    },
    {
        output: "world",
    },
    {
        output: "world",
    },
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
]
```

Desired output would look like this:

```
(2)testing    
hello    
(2)world    
testing
```

How can I remove duplicates if they are **next to each other** and add a counter that displays how many duplicate messages are in a **row**. And the output should look something like this

```
const newArray = [
    {
        output: "testing",
        count: 2
    },
    {
        output: "hello",
        count: 1
    },
    {
        output: "world",
        count: 2
    },

    {
        output: "testing",
        count: 1
    },
]
```

I thought something like this maybe

```js
const array = [{
    output: "testing",
  },
  {
    output: "testing",
  },
  {
    output: "hello",
  },
  {
    output: "world",
  },
  {
    output: "world",
  },
  {
    output: "testing",
  },
]
let newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (newArray.length.length > 1 && array[i].output == newArray[newArray.length - 1].output) {
    newArray[newArray.length - 1].counter += 1
  } else {
    newArray.push({
      output: array[i].output,
      counter: 0
    })
  }

}
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Mitya my bad updated, cant manage to solve this easy problem got a bit frustrated hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: now it groups entries which are close to each other

```js
const array = [
    { output: "testing" },
    { output: "testing" },
    { output: "hello" },
    { output: "world" },
    { output: "world" },
    { output: "testing" }
];

// Result objects
let subRes = false;
const res = [];

// Loop
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // Create count obj
  if(!subRes) subRes = {
    output: array[i].output,
    count: 1
  }
  // If next is the same
  if(array[i+1] && array[i+1].output === array[i].output) {
    subRes.count++;
  } else {
    res.push(subRes);
    subRes = false;
  }
}

// Log
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account if the items are next to each other or not

Comment: Check it now, is this what you was trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array and then print

Example below

```js
var array = [
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
    {
        output: "hello",
    },
    {
        output: "world",
    },
    {
        output: "world",
    },
    {
        output: "testing",
    },
]

// You can reduce to reduce the array in to single object
data = array.reduce((acc, val) => {  
  if(val.output === acc.last_value){
    acc.result[acc.result.length - 1].count += 1;
  } else {
    acc.result.push({...val, count: 1})
  }
  
  acc.last_value = val.output;
  return acc;
}, {result: [], last_value: null});

console.log(data.result);
```

Comment: I dont want to get unique items i need to get the count of same items if they are next to a similar one in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to manage this and reuse it more easily.

Version 1

```
const array = [...]

const reduceCount = (acc, obj) => {
  const key = obj["output"];
  // check if we already store the key
  if(!(key in acc)){
    //the key is not register yet, so we create a counter state
    acc[key] = {count: 0};
  }

  //increment the key state counter
  acc[key]['count'] += 1
  
  return acc;
}

// Reduce the array to get state of each key
const dictCount = array.reduce(reduceCount, {});

console.log(dictCount) // { testing: { count: 3 }, hello: { count: 1 }, world: { count: 2 } }

const newArray = Object.keys(dictCount).map(key => ({
  output: key, 
  count: dictCount[key]['count']
}));

console.log(newArray) 

/** output
[
  { output: 'testing', count: 3 },
  { output: 'hello', count: 1 },
  { output: 'world', count: 2 }
]
 */
```

Version 2: a more reusable way:

```
const array = [...]

const reduceCount = target => (acc, obj) => {
  const key = obj[target];
  // check if we already store the key
  if(!(key in acc)){
    //the key is not register yet, so we create a counter state
    acc[key] = {count: 0};
  }

  //increment the key state counter
  acc[key]['count'] += 1
  
  return acc;
}

const counterState = target => arr => arr.reduce(reduceCount(target), {});
const counterStateOutput = counterState('output'); //specialize the function

// transform state to array
const stateToArray = state =>  Object.keys(state).map(key => ({
  key,
  count: state[key]["count"]
}));

console.log(stateToArray(counterStateOutput(array))) 
//or
console.log(stateToArray(counterState('output')(array))) 

/** output
[
  { key: 'testing', count: 3 },
  { key: 'hello', count: 1 },
  { key: 'world', count: 2 }
]
 */
```